# How to stop body scroll if open menu in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

How can I stop the body scrolling if I open a menu on a mobile device?

```
function bodyScrollStop() {
  $('.header .navbar .navbar-toggler i').on('click', function (event) {
    $('body').toggleClass("onScroll");
  });
}
bodyScrollStop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Plz add this in css..

```
body.onScroll {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for give me solution but I actually  want when i click on navigation menu icon on mobile screen

Comment: ok no pbs -:) You can use whatever you want.. but you can add the class when click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Well i believe that you are showing that toggle button on mobile screens only. Then you can try below code.

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vieckys/a7y0u59r/4/)

JS Code:

```
function bodyScrollStop() {
  $('.header .navbar .navbar-toggler i').on('click', function (event) {
    $('body').toggleClass("no-scroll");
  });
}
bodyScrollStop();
```

CSS:

```
i {
  background: green;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now if you click on that toggler body will get dynamic class and will prevent it from scrolling.

Let me know if you need more help.